# Compiling android x86 for Surface RT with ARM?

Tags: android, x86, arm, surface

I have a Surface RT with Windows 10 on ARM and an unlocked secure boot but I would be curious to see if I could compile android x86 but for ARM. There are no kernel trees and device trees available for this device because it's a Windows device.

I am choosing the Android x86 project because it compiles the android build to an iso to easily install it and it's more like a linux distribution such as Ubuntu.

I searched for some documentation but it says something about a depreciated ARM emulator but nothing else: https://www.android-x86.org/documentation/customize_kernel.html

I know that android x86 is meant for x86 but before I waste my time to download the source, what can I do to actually compile it for ARM, or is it possible? Can someone get me in the right direction?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: This seems REALLY roundabout. Normal Android primarily runs on ARM, and Android-x86 is basically a port. You're asking how to port the port back where it came from.